# Database handler globally as Singleton pattern in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing an application which have a local database for offline support. So I am using Sqlite.net.pcl plugin and its working fine for all Create, Insert, Update and Delete table for every class model.

But instead of creating a separate database activities like insert, get, update for each Model class, I tried to worked on singeton pattern of common database handler(DatabasHandler.cs).

This is my code which I tried to workout singleton pattern,

```
public void CreateTable<T>() where T : new()
{
    var myClass = new T();
    myDatabase.CreateTableAsync<T>().Wait();
}
```

I called this function from my EmployeeViewModel class like this;

```
App.Database.CreateTable<EmployeeModel>();
```

here EmployeeModel is a model class and its worked fine, also the above function is successfully created a Employee Table. Doing the same way I created rest of the Tables from each ViewModel like this;

```
App.Database.CreateTable<SalaryModel>(); // call from SalaryViewModel Page
App.Database.CreateTable<EmployeeAttendanceModel>(); // call from AttendanceViewModel Page
```

**Next:** So how can I insert and get all list items into DatabaseHandler.cs using same (Create Table)singleton pattern. My question is;

1. How should I create a method for Insert/Get/Update a list in DatabaseHandler.cs(Singleton class)?
2. How should I call those method(Insert/Get/Update) from its viewmodel?
   Please help me,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I had a similar thing in my Old XF app this is how I implemented the Singleton this will also answer your first question:

> How should I create a method for Insert/Get/Update a list in DatabaseHandler.cs(Singleton class)?

```
public class DatabaseHandler: IDisposable
{
private SQLiteConnection conn;
//public static string sqlpath;
private bool disposed = false;

private static readonly Lazy<DatabaseHandler> database = new Lazy<DatabaseHandler>(() => new DatabaseHandler());
private DatabaseHandler() { }
public static DatabaseHandler Database
{
    get
    {
        return database.Value;
    }
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposed)
        return;

    if (disposing)
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    disposed = true;
}

public bool InitDatabase()
{
    var ifExist = true;
    try
    {
        this.CreateDatabase();

        ifExist = TableExists(nameof(LocationModel), conn);
        if (!ifExist)
            this.CreateTable<LocationModel>();


        return true;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static bool TableExists(String tableName, SQLiteConnection connection)
{
    var cmd = connection.CreateCommand("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = @name", new object[] { tableName });
    //cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = @name";
    //cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", DbType.String).Value = tableName;

    string tabledata = cmd.ExecuteScalar<string>();
    return (cmd.ExecuteScalar<string>() != null);
}
public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
{
    var sqliteFilename = "xamdblocal.db3";
    string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder
    var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);
    Console.WriteLine(path);
    if (!File.Exists(path)) File.Create(path);
    //var plat = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
    var conn = new SQLiteConnection(path);
    // Return the database connection 
    return conn;
}

private bool CreateDatabase()
{       
    conn = GetConnection();
    string str = conn.DatabasePath;
    return true;
}

public bool CreateTable<T>()
    where T : new()
{
    conn.DropTable<T>();
    conn.CreateTable<T>();
    return true;
}

public bool InsertIntoTable<T>(T LoginData)
    where T : new()
{
    conn.Insert(LoginData);
    return true;
}

public bool InsertBulkIntoTable<T>(IList<T> LoginData)
   where T : class //new()
{
    conn.InsertAll(LoginData);
    return true;
}    

public List<T> SelectDataFromTable<T>()
  where T : new()
{
    try
    {
        return conn.Table<T>().ToList();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public List<T> SelectTableDatafromQuery<T>(string query)
    where T : new()
{
    return conn.Query<T>(query, new object[] { })
                .ToList();
}

public bool UpdateTableData<T>(string query)
    where T : new()
{
    conn.Query<T>(query);
    return true;
}

public void UpdateTableData<T>(IEnumerable<T> query)
    where T : new()
{
    conn.UpdateAll(query);
}

public void UpdateTableData<T>(T query)
   where T : new()
{
    conn.Update(query);
}   

public bool DeleteTableData<T>(T LoginData)
{
    conn.Delete(LoginData);
    return true;
}

public bool DeleteTableDataFromPrimaryKey<T>(object primaryKey)
{
    conn.Delete(primaryKey);
    return true;
}

public bool DeleteTableDataFromQuery<T>(string query)
    where T : new()
{
    conn.Query<T>(query);
    return true;
}
}
```

> How should I call those method(Insert/Get/Update) from its viewmodel? Please help me,

Now for Eg: you want to insert location's Lat Long in your local database where your local model looks something like this:

```
public class LocationModel
{
    [AutoIncrement, PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

So first what you will do is create an instance of LocationModel something like this:

```
var locationModel = new LocationModel
        {
            Latitude = location.Latitude,
            Longitude = location.Longitude
        };

Then insert it something like this:

DatabaseHandler.Database.InsertIntoTable<LocationModel>(locationModel);
```

Also, do not forget to add the `SQLiteNetExtensions` in your project for Linq support.

Goodluck feel free to revert in case of queries

Comment: Thanks @G.hakim I tried your code its working except, here is an error I am getting, when I call this method public List<T> SelectDataFromTable<T>() from my viewmodel

Comment: Error is cannot implicit conversion system threading task to system.collection.Generics

Comment: I am calling this method like employeeDBList = App.Database.SelectDataFromTable<EmployeeModel>(); also My model is List so I changed the method like this public Task<List<T>> SelectDataFromTable<T>() where T : new() in DatabaseHandler.cs

Comment: I do not think you can do that if you want to use async types use the SqliteAsync!

Comment: The error is gone when I added employeeDBList = await App.Database.SelectDataFromTable<EmployeeModel>();

Comment: I would recommend you use the SqliteAsync library for this as it is made for this purpose in any case if that works for you good!

Comment: Thanks @G.hakim, its worked fine what I need. Thanks a lot